# Reading style property with Jquery

Tags: jquery, background, styles

I have something like this on my page.

```
<div class="number_1" style="background-color:red"></div>
<div class="number_2" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
<div class="number_3"></div>
<div class="number_4"></div>
<div class="number_5" style="background-color:red"></div>
```

I cant change HTML code by adding the class for background-color! It must red from style!

I need function like this

```
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if($('.number_'+i).hasBackgroundColor('red')){
        //something
    }else{
        //somethign else
    }
}
```

`.attr('style')==='background-color: red'` dont seem to work

`.css('background-color')` also dont seem to work

Comment: how are you using .css() ?

Comment: JQuery has .css() for this. Have a look at their documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/css/ . They also have a nice demonstration of it.

Comment: Actually, attr('style') working, just IE returns different string from the rest of the browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you get the background-color:

```
var backgroundColor = $('.number_'+i).css('background-color');
```

It will return something like "rgb(245, 180, 5)". Red color is "rgb(255,0,0)".

If you prefer getting hexa value, for example #ff0000 for red color, use such a function:

```
function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

Comment: I *think* some browsers may return `rgba` rather than `rgb`, and I *think* some even sometimes return hex codes. Just FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

css('background-color') return color in rgb in your case "rgb(255,0,0)".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method which return in rgb.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {    
    if ($('.number_' + i).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") { 
    //something    
    } else {
        //somethign else
    }
}
```

As T.J. Crowder mention, the above code works only in chrome and not in firefox or IEs.

Also try using [RGB color parser in JavaScript](http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/)

Comment: @ user: That's an improvement. Be aware, though, that different browsers return the value in different ways (with and without spaces, for instance, sometimes they return `rgba` rather than `rgb`, and I *think* some even sometimes return hex codes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if($('.number_'+i).css('background-color')=='red'){ // or ==rgb(255,0,0)
        //something
    }else{
        //somethign else
    }
}
```

Comment: I think css('background-color') will always return 'rbg(...,...,...)'

Comment: @Ricola3D: Yeah, `rgb` or I *think* on some browsers you might get a hex color code. Certainly not `"red"`.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder Just for curiosity (and for futur works), what versions of browsers return an hexa code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.each($('div') , function(index) {
alert($(this).attr('style'));
});
});
```

And, then add your additional logic/conditions in loop...

something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.each($('div') , function(index) {

style=$(this).attr('style');

if(style=='background-color: red;' || style=='background-color:red') {

    alert($(this).attr('class')+' is red!');

}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.attr('style')==='background-color: red' dont seem to work`

One space will give different results:

`$('<div style="background-color:red"></div>').attr('style') === 'background-color: red'`

false

`$('<div style="background-color:red"></div>').attr('style') === 'background-color:red'`

true